# How to integrate firebase test lab with circleci

Tags: android, firebase, continuous-integration, circleci, firebase-test-lab

Hi I want to test my app on firebase test lab. I want to integrate it with circleci. I have read this document https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/firebase-test-lab/ and created config.yml

I have created `GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY` in the environment variable of circleci but it is not testing app on firebase test lab.

config.yml

```
version: 2.0

defaults: &defaults
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-27-alpha
    working_directory: ~/github-jobs
    environment:
      JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Xmx1024m"
      GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.workers.max=2 -Dkotlin.incremental=false"
      TERM: dumb

gcloud_config: &gcloud_config
  working_directory: ~/github-jobs
  docker:
    - image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
  environment:
    TERM: dumb

update_sdk: &update_sdk
  name: Update SDK
  command: |
    mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
    echo "d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
    echo "84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
    sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27"

jobs:
  build:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - run:
          <<: *update_sdk
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "base/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "instantapp/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "main/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "tv/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: chmod permissions
          command: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew dependencies --no-daemon
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "base/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "instantapp/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "main/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "tv/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Assemble APKs
          command: ./gradlew assemble --no-daemon
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle/caches
            - ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/outputs/apk
          destination: apks
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_artifacts:
          path: build/dependencyUpdates
          destination: dependencyUpdates
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: .
          paths:
            - build
            - app/build

# Google Cloud Service

export_gcloud_key: &export_gcloud_key
  run:
    name: Export Google Cloud Service key environment variable
    command: echo 'export GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY="$GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY"' >> $BASH_ENV
decode_gcloud_key: &decode_gcloud_key
  run:
    name: Decode Google Cloud credentials
    command: echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY | base64 -di > ${HOME}/client-secret.json

test_instrumented:
  <<: *gcloud_config
  steps:
    - *export_gcloud_key
    - *decode_gcloud_key
    - run:
        name: Set Google Cloud target project
        command: gcloud config set project dazzling-fire-5515
    - run:
        name: Authenticate with Google Cloud
        command: gcloud auth activate-service-account firebase-circleci@dazzling-fire-5515.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file ${HOME}/client-secret.json
    - run:
        name: Run instrumented test on Firebase Test Lab
        command: gcloud firebase test android run --type instrumentation --app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk --test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk --device model=Nexus5X,version=26,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait --environment-variables coverage=true,coverageFile=/sdcard/tmp/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec --directories-to-pull=/sdcard/tmp --timeout 20m
    - run:
        name: Create directory to store test results
        command: mkdir firebase
    - run:
        name: Download instrumented test results from Firebase Test Lab
        command: gsutil -m cp -r -U "`gsutil ls gs://test-lab-3udbiqpdyp0d0-miwcp7d69v80m | tail -1`*" /root/workspace/firebase/
    - persist_to_workspace:
        root: .
        paths:
          - firebase
    - store_artifacts:
        path: firebase/
        destination: /firebase/

general:
  branches:
    only:
     - master # list of branches to build
     - develop
```

Does anyone know what I am missing ?

Comment: Everything below this line `dependencies:` is CircleCI 1.0 syntax which is wrong. You'll need to convert it to CircleCI 2.0 syntax as a first step.

Comment: @FelicianoTech can you suggest ? I don't know about that

Comment: There's a lot. I would read through the Configuration Reference to learn the syntax: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/

Comment: can you update doc here https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/firebase-test-lab/ ?

Comment: That Doc is a CircleCI 1.0 Doc which is being EOL'd. None of the 1.0 Docs will get updates for new information. There's a small bit of info in the 2.0 Docs: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/#firebase

Comment: There's also CircleCI Discuss with others doing Android builds on CircleCI 2.0: https://discuss.circleci.com/

Comment: @FelicianoTech I have updated according to CircleCI 2.0 but still it is not working, it is not testing app on firebase test lab. I have updated my config in question

Answer (score 2):

For CirlceCI 2.0 there are just [Firebase & GCP Deployment](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/#firebase) examples; which are not really applicable here... the `gcloud` part is rather relevant, because the docs at 
[Using Firebase Test Lab with Continuous Integration Systems](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/continuous) refer to it:

```
gcloud firebase test android run --app <local_server_path>/<app_apk>.apk --test <local_server_path>/<app_test_apk>.apk
```

On CircleCI 2.0 the `gcloud` command appears to be `sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud`. as well as it is being described here, a) how to obtain the exit codes and b) what they actually mean: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line#running_your_instrumentation_tests

The problem description of "is not testing app" is not sufficient to tell what exactly is wrong. I'd assume, the command initiating the instrumentation test should throw some error or some complaint; please provide further details (logs).

I've just found one article on Medium, which seems to be what you're looking for: [All you need to know about CircleCI 2.0 with Firebase Test Lab](https://medium.com/@ayltai/all-you-need-to-know-about-circleci-2-0-with-firebase-test-lab-2a66785ff3c2) (there is another one [article](https://medium.com/pink-room-club/android-continuous-integration-using-fastlane-and-circleci-2-0-part-ii-7f8dd7265659), which is also utilizing FastLane).